# AD Account Mapping between Forests (SharePoint to Exchange)

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, exchange-server

I am working with SharePoint 2013 on-premise and I am running into an issue with the 'Sync to Outlook' task button.

When I try syncing the tasks to Outlook, the ULS logs read "`401 Unauthorized ....reason=`"`The tenant for realm 'my.domain.com does not exist.....`";

I have determined that my issue is the SharePoint 2013 server is in one Forest  and the Exchange 2013 server is in another. There is a discrepancy with the domain resolution, as SharePoint is requesting `accountname@my.domain.com` but Exchange expects `accountname@another.domain.com`

Is there a way I could setup a mapping for the Exchange security token (from SharePoint, or vice versa) that would translate the domain or realm that the user account should be resolved to in such a case? The base username is the same, but the domain is different.

Comment: i think you may need to server-to-server authetication check this one https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218665%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have performed that step @waqasSarwarMCSE but now I am faced with this error. Is there a switch that would allow me to specify the realm to be resolved?

Comment: can you share the complete error?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE There is a lot of server specific information in the errors, and I have performed a fairly thorough analysis of the issue. Is there something unclear with my question?

Comment: do you have both realm created? for my.doamin and another.domain.com

Comment: Yes, but they are on different servers. SharePoint 2013 is in the realm for my.domain and Exchange 2013 is in the realm for another.domain The issue arises when passing AD credentials between the two realms, as Exchange cannot identify the user @my.domain.

Comment: @waqassarwarMCSE thanks for your assistance, but I was able to find a reolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually ended up being an issue of accepted domains on the Exchange server. I was having an issue because the email domain (another.domain.com), and the AD domain (my.domain.com) differs. The following PowerShell command will register the source (SharePoint 2013) domain on the Exchange Server:

```
New-AcceptedDomain 'my.domain.com' -DomainName 'Whatever I wanna call it' -DomainType 'internalrelay'
```

In a nutshell, this allows Exchange to accept the unknown domain, and resolve the account name appropriately against it's Exchange Organizations.